# tsconfig: folder in include - recursive or not?

Tags: typescript

Will a `tsconfig.json` with:

```
 "include": [
        "src"
    ]
```

recursively include all `.ts` files under `src/` or not?

- [Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include) suggest a glob (`src/**/*`) is required. As-well-as [the handbook](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/tutorials/Migrating%20from%20JavaScript.md#writing-a-configuration-file).
- A trial with a [some sample](https://github.com/S-A-Ivanov/tscolorballs) off github suggests the opposite:

```
$ tsc --listFiles > orig
$ grep -v node_modules orig|cut -c 35-
src/core/Board.ts
src/core/Engine.ts
src/core/Point.ts
src/core/ProcessState.ts
src/core/Situation.ts
src/core/TileState.ts
src/core/main.ts
$ vim tsconfig.json // change 'src/**/*' to 'src'
$ tsc --listFiles > noglob
$ diff -s orig noglob
Files orig and noglob are identical
```

- As I understand it, [this merged PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/11495) would explain the above result. Yet this behaviour isn't reflected in the docs.

So, which is it? Is it true that `src/**/*` is just a verbose equivalent of `src`?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

not according to what i know `src` will only look for the file `index.ts` or not (as far as I remember some versions of typescript@dev don't even accept a path as a directory) and its dependencies.

`src/**/*` is a `glob` it means find all subfiles starting from `src/`